# Smooth character movement on an Isometric map

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, isometric

I have an Isometric engine that I am building:

http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/09h43kz7/1/

(Arrow keys to move).

I am updating the `Engine.player.x` and `Engine.player.y` to move the character, but (obviously) the player just "pops" from one tile to another.

*I wondered if there was a way to make him "slide" from tile to tile?*
*Or better still, free movement...*

I've been pulling my hair out trying.

Here's the relevant code:

```
var Engine = {

    // canvas variables
    canvas: null,
    ctx: null,

    // map
    map: [
        [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
        [2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2],
        [2,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2],
        [2,2,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,2],
        [2,2,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,2],
        [2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,2],
        [2,2,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
        [2,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,2],
        [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
        [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,2],
        [2,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2],
        [2,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,2],
        [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,2],
        [2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2],
        [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
    ],

    // player info
    player: {
        x:1,
        y:1
    },

    // tile size
    tileH: 31,
    tileW: 63,

    // map position
    mapX: window.innerWidth/2,
    mapY: window.innerHeight/3,

    // tile images
    tileSources: [
        "images/stone.png",
        "images/grass.png",
        "images/water.png",
        "images/ralph.png"
    ],

    // for pre-loading
    tileGraphics: [],
    tilesLoaded: 0,

    // image preloader
    loadImages: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < Engine.tileSources.length; i++) {
            Engine.tileGraphics[i] = new Image();
            Engine.tileGraphics[i].src = Engine.tileSources[i];
            Engine.tileGraphics[i].onload = function() {
                Engine.tilesLoaded++;
                if (Engine.tilesLoaded === Engine.tileSources.length) {
                    Engine.draw();
                }
            }
        }
    },

    // update logic
    update: function() {
        Engine.draw();
    },

    // draw the scene
    draw: function() {
        Engine.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, Engine.canvas.width, Engine.canvas.height);
        var drawTile;
        for (var i = 0; i < Engine.map.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < Engine.map[i].length; j++) {
                drawTile = Engine.map[i][j];
                Engine.ctx.drawImage(Engine.tileGraphics[drawTile], (i - j) * Engine.tileH + Engine.mapX, (i + j) * Engine.tileH / 2 + Engine.mapY);
                if (Engine.player.x === i && Engine.player.y === j) {
                    Engine.ctx.drawImage(Engine.tileGraphics[3], (i - j) * Engine.tileH + Engine.mapX, (i + j) * Engine.tileH / 2 + Engine.mapY - Engine.tileH + 10);
                }
            }
        }
        Engine.gameLoop();
    },

    // game loop
    gameLoop: function() {
        Engine.gameTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            requestAnimFrame(Engine.update, Engine.canvas);
        }, 1);
    },

    // start
    init: function() {
        Engine.canvas = document.getElementById("main");
        Engine.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        Engine.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        Engine.ctx = Engine.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
            //console.log(e.keyCode);
            switch(e.keyCode) {
                case 38:
                    if (Engine.map[Engine.player.x-1][Engine.player.y] !== 2) {
                        Engine.player.x--;
                    }
                    break;
                case 40:
                    if (Engine.map[Engine.player.x+1][Engine.player.y] !== 2) {
                        Engine.player.x++;
                    }
                    break;
                case 39:
                    if (Engine.map[Engine.player.x][Engine.player.y-1] !== 2) {
                        Engine.player.y--;
                    }
                    break;
                case 37:
                    if (Engine.map[Engine.player.x][Engine.player.y+1] !== 2) {
                        Engine.player.y++;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        });
        Engine.loadImages();
    }

}


// loaded
window.onload = function() {
    Engine.init();
};


// request animation frame
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame || 
    function (callback, element){
    fpsLoop = window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
  };
}());
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By what I seen, when the player moves, just up 1 time the X and Y coordenates value, and by this it has to pop?

Comment: When you move - it moves the character straight to the new tile. But I'd like it to smoothly slide to the next tile.

Comment: If possible, try to make a interval that will going increasing the player X/Y a bit while itself is moving to another tile, after that the player be over the tile, clear the interval. This is, by example, `I'm here, I'm moving, 1, 2, 3, I'm here`

Comment: @ProHands could you give me a sample bit of code so I can understand it a bit better?

Comment: `/* firstly create a variable called "b" for the interval in somewhere, and the next interval is for some movement that is beginning */ b=setInterval(function(){if(/* check if the player is over the new tile */){clearInterval(b);/* this clear the interval */}else{/* Increase or decrease some coordenate value of the player with some value like 0.2 or lessen. */}},15);` - something like this

Comment: I edited the comment.

Comment: I can see how this works, but I cannot see how to integrate this into my Engine.draw() function. Is there a way of doing this without a new timer?

Comment: Hm, maybe not. But this isn't for the `draw` function, and yeah for `init`, where so it's possible to see the player X/Y being changed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to understand you - if you have a working solution, could you post it as an answer rather than a comment...?

Comment: Hm, I'll try to bring something useful by testing.

Comment: I just didn't get it why when I make the player X increase or decrease 0.2 in value makes the player invisible...

Comment: Ah, it's because it's only rendering exact co-ordinates. 0.2 is inbetween tiles.

Comment: Then they can't anymore be exact because then it'll not be possible to smooth the character movement, you have to move bit per bit the player while going to a new tile.

Comment: For free movements, on keydown add a new requestAnimationFrame that will move your character by float value. on keyup, cancel the animation. each new keydown will update the direction. If nobody has done it yet, I may implement it for you tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing the character at tile positions. What you want is to just add a second set of coordinates for the character representing its destination. To move smoothly you can set the characters position in fractions of a tile. Eg player.x = 2.5 the character is halfway between tiles 2 and 3.

Also you want to get rid of the messing about in isometric space. Off load the transformation from 2d to isometric to the draw function, rather than doing it by hand each time you draw to the playfield.

Create the draw function

```
// add to the Engine object.
// img is the image to draw. x and y are the tile locations. 
// offsetX and offsetY [optional] are pixel offsets for fine tuning;
drawImageIso:function (img,x,y,offsetX,offsetY){
    offsetX = offsetX === undefined ? 0: offsetX; // so you dont have to 
    offsetY = offsetY === undefined ? 0: offsetY; // add the offset if you 
                                                  // are not using it;
    Engine.ctx.drawImage(  // draw the image
        img,
        (x - y) * Engine.tileH + Engine.mapX + offsetX, 
        (x + y) * Engine.tileH / 2 + Engine.mapY - Engine.tileH+offsetY
    );
},
```

Change the player object to

```
player: {
    x:1,
    y:1,
    destX:1,  // the destination tile
    destY:1,   
    playerAtDest:true, // true if the player has arrived     
},
```

Add this befor the tile render loops

```
    var p = Engine.player; // because I am lazy and dont like typing.
    var dx = p.destX;
    var dy = p.destY;
    var maxPlayerSpeed = 0.1;  // max speed in tiles per frame
    var mps = maxPlayerSpeed; // because I am lazy
    // check if the player needs to move
    if( Math.abs(p.x - dx) > mps  || Math.abs(p.y - dy) > mps ){
        p.x += Math.max( -mps , Math.min( mps , dx - p.x )); // move to destination clamping speed;
        p.y += Math.max( -mps , Math.min( mps , dy - p.y ));            
        p.playerAtDest = false;  // flag the player is on the way
    }else{
        // player directly over a till and not moving;
        p.x = dx; // ensure the player positioned correctly;
        p.y = dy;
        p.playerAtDest = true;  // flag the player has arrived
    }
```

Add the following where you used to draw the player. Use the destination x,y to determine when to draw or use `Math.round(Engine.player.x)` and y to determine when.

```
    // now draw the player at its current position
    Engine.drawImageIso( Engine.tileGraphics[3] , p.x , p.y , 0 , 10);
```

You will have to change the interface to move player destination rather than x and y. You may also want to delay the move until the player has arrived at the current destination.

That covers the basics.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks very much. Works lovely. But now I have a zOrdering issue with the trees :( http://jsfiddle.net/vvu4ydxo/1/

Comment: Glad it helped you out,. The best way to deal with the Z order is to draw from back to front. You can end up with some ambiguity as to what is in front at times. It is a common problem so try looking for an existing answer. If you can find one make up another question.